# Remove items by clicking ok alert js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to remove some items in a shopping cart if they don't exist anymore. When i open the shopping cart, an alert comes up and display which items will be removed. What i want is remove that item by responding ok to the alert.
I have a js code that remove item row by row from the shopping cart by clicking the specific icon, but i can't call the function/js code inside my php and do what i want directly from the alert.

js code for removing items row by row from the shopping cart

del-cart.js:

```
$jq('.delArt').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idArt = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    var Cart = new CartService();
    Cart.deleteArt(idArt);

});
```

cart.js:

```
deleteArt(idArt){
        var item = this.cart.get(idArt);
        this.cart.set('totPriceCart',this.cart.get('totPriceCart') - item.totPrice);
        this.cart.set('totPiecesCart',this.cart.get('totPiecesCart') - item.totPieces);
        this.cart.del(idArt);
        this.saveCart('/cart', '/cartnew/save','do not save');  
    }
```

this is my php code where i check if there aren't items from the db:

```
if(!empty($repo->profileArt($artCarr->idDb))){
                $art = $repo->profileArt($artCarr->idDb);
            } else {
                $message = $art[0];
                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='/jquery.min.js'></script>";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='/del-cart.js'></script>";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='/cart.js'></script>";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Item $message not available anymore and will be removed');
 var ttt = document.getElementsByClassName('delArt')[0];
    ('.delArt').onclick = function() {
       var idArt = this.getAttribute($message);
    var Cart = new CartService();
Cart.deleteArt(idArt);
    };
```

But it doesn't work of course... any ides? TNXXX

Comment: so, cant i use the reply to the alert in order to remove items? i can do that from the cart if the items are in the DB;

Comment: Why does it matter if they click OK?  Are you going to leave an item that doesn't exist in the cart if they don't click OK?

Comment: This might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/755307/how-to-raise-an-event-after-ok-click-in-alert-box  you want to setup an onClick event on the confirmation OK in the alert.